# Не работает прокрутка toolbar при прокрутке scrollview

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Делал скрывающийся при прокрутке list view toolbar. Код:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/white1"
tools:context=".InPasta">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



<ScrollView
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/PastaName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PastaText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
            android:letterSpacing="0.05"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Возникла проблема: toolbar пролистывается только если навестись прямо на него. Прошу помочь мне.

Comment: метка android-studio никак не связана с вашей проблемой, просьба использовать ее только в вопросах непосредственно связанных с IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо ScrollView нужно использовать NestedScrollView